# Multiple View paths on Node.js + Express + <%= EJS %>

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using express 4.17.1 combination for my web app.

I am wondering how can i render multiple files depend on  the route  and multiple folders

Let's say that i have :

[image]

When I want to go to the admin path this problem appears :

[image]

Comment: Use the version 4.17.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing an array of directory will not work if you're using express version 3 or above. Try the below

```
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

   var renderer = express.response.render;
      express.render = () => {
        app.set('views', './regular/viewPath/views');
         try {
           return renderer.apply(this, arguments);
          }
        catch (e) {...}

        app.set('views', './admin/viewPath/views');       
        return renderer.apply(this, arguments);
};    

const adminRoute = require('./routes/adminFile');

app.use('/admin', adminRoute);
```

Finally, set the name inside your admin file

```
router.set('name', 'adminFile');
```

Other easy alternative would be to put your views in different folders

Example:

```
 views/index.ejs
 views/admin/adminFile.ejs

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Then on render, you do like

```
res.render('views/admin/adminFile', configs);
```

Comment: Use the version 4.17.1

Comment: I found the dream using different folders